# What is Change the source attachment in android

Tags: android

I am trying to debug a android application. I got error-

"The JAR file C:\Android\android-sdk-windows\platforms\android-8\android.jar has no source attachment"

What is this error exactly?

Thanks.

Comment: destroye avd and add new from android.com

Comment: if you give entire logcat then we can provide any solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be able to try the following:

To attach source code for android.jar, you may follow the tutorial at the link below: http://android.opensourceror.org/2010/01/18/android-source/ Make sure to choose the correct platform version.

Other than that, please post more code for review.

I have seen this being caused before because of a typo.